# microservice seems to work, but there's no data displayed

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a simple app that's supposed to connect to postgres and display content of one of the tables.

I installed postgres, created a table and inserted a row, but nothing is shown when I run it.

This are my `application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=name
spring.datasource.password=pass
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```

and this is repository interface

```
@Repository
public interface TaxonRepository extends CrudRepository<Taxon, Long> {
}
```

and the model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dim_taxon")
public class Taxon{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Getter @Setter
  private Long id;
  @Getter @Setter
  private String name;
  @Getter @Setter
  private String value;
  @Getter @Setter
  private String reserve;
  @Getter @Setter
  private String source;
}
```

My service

```
@Service
public class TaxonService implements TaxonServiceI{
  @Autowired
  private TaxonRepository repository;

  @Override
  public List<Taxon> findAll() {
    return (List<Taxon>) repository.findAll();
  }
}
```

and controller

```
@Controller
public class TaxonController {
  @Autowired
  private TaxonServiceI taxonService;

  @RequestMapping(value="/showTaxons")
  public String homePage(Model model){
    List<Taxon> taxons = taxonService.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("taxons", taxons);
    return "index";
  }

}
```

I tried to add an object manually to check if there was a problem with the html or smth

```
List<Taxon> taxons = new ArrayList<>();
Taxon taxon1 = new Taxon();
taxon1.setName("a");
taxon1.setReserve("a");
taxon1.setSource("a");
taxon1.setValue("a");
taxons.add(taxon1);
model.addAttribute("taxons", taxons);
```

but html is fine. Seems like this

```
List<Taxon> taxons = taxonService.findAll();
```

doesn't work. What's the problem here? There aren't actually any errors.

My table and the data.
[image]

Comment: Are you loading the data using any script sql file like flyway?

Comment: @Alien I don't understand. If you mean in the table, then I use PgAdmin and if from, spring data JPA

Comment: attach Taxon entity

Comment: @alien It's already in the question.

Comment: I don't see an issue with your code, except **(1)** an unnecessary cast (`(List<Taxon>)`) and **(2)** a copy-paste error in your `TaskController` (the service field is listed twice in your snippet). Make sure there isn't a stacktrace or something else in your log.

Comment: Did you commit the insert?

Comment: @Jens Yeah, I have auto commint on

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding your loaded `List<Taxon>` to the model.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/showTaxons")
public String homePage(Model model){
    List<Taxon> taxons = taxonService.findAll();
    return "index";
}
```

Just returns the page to render, without modifying the model. 
So this should work

```
@RequestMapping(value="/showTaxons")
public String homePage(Model model){
    model.add(taxonService.findAll());
    return "index";
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that's a copy past error. That row is actually present

Answer (score 0):

In the end I added a few more anotations

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Validated
@Entity
@Table(name = "table name")
```

And explicit mapping for columns

```
@Column(name = "column_name")
```

this helped